# M2.1.9 : How to override the magento default .phtml file under vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontent\templates\email\items.phtml

Tags: magento2, overrides, view

There.
After success migration work, i need to handle devlopment work,ugh. I'm a mad newbie about Magento2 so could you let me know how to overwrite the default phtml file under vendor/magento .. folder.

## FYI,

Currently, our website has no theme (it means default Luma theme, right?) 
And i was trying to overwrite some phtml files using order confirmation email. (it seems that it is not much related with which theme i'm using tho).

1. Copied templates need to make override in:

`/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml`

2. Location contain templates using to override:

`/public_html/app/design/frontend/Magento/default/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml`

3. Run commands after modification

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   find pub/ -type f ! -perm 0644 -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
   find pub/ -type d ! -perm 0755 -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
   ```

What should i do? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Location seems wrong

**It should be**

> public_html/app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Themename}/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml

**Instead of**

> public_html/app/design/frontend/Magento/default/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml

---

**As your your theme is  luma**  And ***this theme is register*** under `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma`

So,Other should modify code at this located

**Create  a template file `items.phtml` at `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Sales\templates\email`.**

And that new `items.phtml`  you can work.

### Via custom module

*If you **donot want to work** at direct **vendor** folder then you need create a custom module*

This module should consist of below files:

- `app/code/app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/registration.php`
- `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/composer.json`
- `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/etc/module.xml`

**then Create a layout file `sales_email_order_items.xml` at `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/view/frontend/layout`**

On this `sales_email_order_items.xml` add below code for **change the template via layout**.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" 
    label="Email Order Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
     <referenceBlock name="items">
         <arguments>
         <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">{vendorname}_{Company}::sales/email/items.phtml</argument>
         </arguments>
     </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

*Now new template phtml is located at `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/view/frontend/templates/sales/email/items.phtml`*.

Now you do after you want.

After this your should do below

*delete all file from `var/cache` and `var/view_preprocessed`  and page_cache using `rm -rf`var/cache`and`rm -rf var/view_preprocessed`,`rm -rf var/page_cache`*

Comment: Thank you for answering me , Amit. By the way, do i have to put layout file?

Comment: It doesn't work in magento 2.1.9

Comment: is this work?..

Comment: Yes! It works !

Comment: Happy to hear that