# How Do I override adminhtml phtml file without create custom module in Magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides, phtml

I want to override `\magento\module-user\view\adminhtml\templates\admin\fotgotpassword_url.phtml` file without creating a custom module.

Can you please help me How do I solve the problem?

Comment: You have to create an admin theme for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a adminhtml theme to override this phtml.
you have the steps in this link: 
[How to create admin theme for magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59206/how-to-create-admin-theme-for-magento2)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with **create custom module or custom Theme for admin**.

My Suggestion is that a create custom module and changes template from   this module.

See How  to override an module
[M2.1.9 : How to override the magento default .phtml file under vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontent\templates\email\items.phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195923/m2-1-9-how-to-override-the-magento-default-phtml-file-under-vendor-magento-mo/195927#195927)

One of advantage of this process, you can use this ***module for any module template override***.